# How to get third category of woocommerce via category id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried this code to show multi child category via woocommerce category id but getting error. Could you tell me what is wrong?

```
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $number = 66,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<div class="second-menu">';
        foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
            $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
            echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a>' . '</li>';
                $args2 = get_terms('product_cat',array(
                    'child_of' => $sc->term_id,
                    'hierarchical' => 1,
                    'hide_empty' => 1,
                ));
            }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="third-menu">';
            foreach ($args2 as $subsubCats) {
                $SubLinks = get_term_link($subsubCats->slug, $subsubCats->taxonomy);
                echo '<li><a href=' . $SubLinks . '>' . $subsubCats->name . '</a>' .'</li>';
                }
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: I tried your code and didn't get any error, if you are getting any error then let me know what error it is. and try once doing 'hide_empty' => 0, in $args2

Comment: I has tried to to add but my site not load. my site is bepnamphat.vn . and now I used this code to get sub menu but just get second level category: <?php woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID('1291'); ?> , I want to get second and third level category.

Answer (score 2):

ok so now I got the problem from your code. As you want 2 levels of subcategories, you are writing 2 foreach loop which is correct but you need to add second foreach loop as nested loop of first foreach. I have done some change in your code to get 2 levels subcatecories and proper layout.

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => $number = 66,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<div class="second-menu">';
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
    $link = get_term_link($sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy);
    echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $sc->name . '</a>';
        echo '<div class="third-menu">';
            $args2 = get_terms('product_cat', array(
                'child_of' => $sc->term_id,
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'hide_empty' => 1
            ));
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($args2 as $subsubCats) {
                    $SubLinks = get_term_link($subsubCats->slug, $subsubCats->taxonomy);
                    echo '<li><a href=' . $SubLinks . '>' . $subsubCats->name . '</a>' . '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';

wp_reset_query();
```